Definition feels contradictory (Computational Complexity Theory)
I studied a definition for time complexity:
Let $M$ be a deterministic Turing Machine. The running time of $M$ is said to be:

for a function $t: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ ($\mathbb{N}$ is natural number) and for all $x$ belonging to $\Sigma^*$,
$M$ halts in at most $O(t(|x|)$ steps.

My question is that $x$ belonging to $\Sigma^*$ means $x$ could very well be $\varepsilon$ (empty string) for which $|x| = 0$.
How is $t(0)$ computed as 0 is not a natural number.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Wikipedia/Is 0 a natural number? That's a fun discussion!! Thanks for the laughs

Is that word for word the definition in the book? It's weird. "For all x, M halts in at most O(t(|x|)) steps"? If x is already quantified by "for all", then t(|x|) is a constant and it doesn't make sense to talk about big-O...

@Stef yes, and the same has been mentioned for s(|x|) where 's' is the space complexity function. I think O(t|x|) point is irrelevant in discussion as the entire point of using big-O is to ignore certain stuff like multiplication by constants and lower order terms. What's really bothering me is that I am not able to understand what part of this definition feels weird, is it 0 being a natural number (or not) or is it x belonging to Σ*.

@OM_anand Whether or not |x|=0 is allowed by the definition really couldn't matter less. The only thing important in the definition is what happens in the limit. You could add any arbitrary constraint like |x| > 0 or |x| > 1 or |x| > 42 or |x| > 137 in that definition and the resulting definitions would all be equivalent. What is important in that definition is what happens when |x| grows, not when |x| is small. But the definition is a bit sloppily written.

@Stef makes sense. Thanks!

$\mathbb{N}$ can be defined as the set of non-negative integers 0, 1, 2, ...
You should check the definition in the book you're reading.
However, there is no contradiction regardless of how $\mathbb{N}$ is defined. It might just be a tiny mistake that I'm sure you're able to fix.

Thanks for the quick reply. It was mentioned that ℕ here is a "natural number". So I had begun to think that instead of x belonging to Σ* (U Σ^i; i>=0), they would have probably meant x belonging to Σ+(U Σ^i; i>0). Not sure if that fix makes sense.
